SSH session over ipv6 feezes after short time, works fine over ipv4
I have set up a server and a router (two machines) with both ipv4 and ipv6 (ULA).
Ubuntu Version: 24.04.
When using ipv4 for both ssh and cockpit everything works fine.
On the other hand, when using ipv6 following happens:

connecting to ssh works and i get a session, but after typing ~5 letters in the terminal, session freezes. after a long time, it can recover, but again gets frozen after typing a few chars into the terminal
signing in into cockpit doesnt work (gui gets displayed, but somehow seems very slow to get shown in the browser)

ssh client log (aaa i started typing just to put some chars into the session, after which it got stuck):
debug3: obfuscate_keystroke_timing: starting: interval ~20ms
aaaadebug3: obfuscate_keystroke_timing: stopping: chaff time expired (162 chaff packets sent)

<manually issuing logout after long recovery by pressing ctrl-d>

logout
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 [session] r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

debug3: obfuscate_keystroke_timing: stopping: no active channels (0 chaff packets sent)
debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to router closed.
Transferred: sent 9636, received 11784 bytes, in 444.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 21.7, received 26.5
debug1: Exit status 130


cockpit log
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit-wsinstance-http.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service http instance...
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance factory...
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Listening on cockpit-wsinstance-http.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service http instance.
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Listening on cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance factory.
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit.service - Cockpit Web Service...
Jun 20 16:23:07 router.lan systemd[1]: Started cockpit.service - Cockpit Web Service.
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Started cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory@5-4594-110.service - Cockpit Web Service https instance factory (PID 4594/UID 110).
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Starting cockpit-wsinstance-https@e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855...
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Listening on cockpit-wsinstance-https@e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.socket - Socket for Cockpit Web Service https instance e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: Started cockpit-wsinstance-https@e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.service - Cockpit Web Service https instance e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.
Jun 20 16:23:08 router.lan systemd[1]: cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory@5-4594-110.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan cockpit-session[4607]: pam_ssh_add: Failed adding some keys
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan cockpit-session[4607]: pam_unix(cockpit:session): session opened for user x(uid=1000) by x(uid=0)
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan systemd-logind[745]: New session 82 of user x.
Jun 20 16:24:14 router.lan systemd[1]: Started session-82.scope - Session 82 of User x.
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan cockpit-session[4607]: pam_unix(cockpit:session): session closed for user x
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan systemd[1]: session-82.scope: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan systemd-logind[745]: Session 82 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jun 20 16:24:29 router.lan systemd-logind[745]: Removed session 82.

does anyone know what could cause this?
